# Expo On-Air Update Channel Flag is disabled

Tags: react-native, expo

I was using expo release-channel for "on-air updates". And it was working well, until that day.

I used command like:

```
expo publish --release-channel staging-v2
```

And it returns;

```
» ios: Expo.plist key: "EXUpdatesReleaseChannel": The value passed to the --release-channel flag is to "staging-v2", but it is set to "default". https://expo.fyi/expo-updates-config.md
» android: AndroidManifest.xml key "expo.modules.updates.EXPO_RELEASE_CHANNEL": The value passed to the --release-channel flag is "staging-v2", but it is set to "default". https://expo.fyi/expo-updates-config.md
```

But It was working well until today. And I didn't change anything at that stage.

Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Have you find an answer?